# If there is continuous surjective $g: X \to \{ 0,1 \}$ and continuous $f: X \to Y$ then there exists a continuous surjective $h: f(X) \to \{0,1 \}$

Tags: general-topology

Assume $X,Y$ are topological spaces. This is equivalent to proving that if $f: X \to Y$ is continuous and $f(X)$ is connected then $X$ is connected. I need to prove this directly the way I wrote it. Is there any way to prove this without using connectedness (or with a minor usage)?

EDIT

This statements are equivalent but false. As pointed out in the comments, just define $f$ as a constant function and take $X$ to be any disconnected topological space

Comment: It's obvious that $f(X)$ connected cannot imply $X$ connected. Let $X$ be any disconnected space you like, and define $f:X\to Y$ to be a _constant_ function.

Comment: Neither of the two statements are true (as David points out)

Comment: You want to prove a fact about connectedness without using connectedness? Seems a contradictio in terminis.. What statements are exactly equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused by your question. If $X$ is connected, and $f: X \to Y$ is continuous then one can show that $f[X]$ is connected as follows: suppose not. Then there is a continuous surjective $g: f[X] \to \{0,1\}$. But then $g \circ f: X \to \{0,1\}$ is also continuous and surjective, contradicting connectedness of $X$. So $f[X]$ is connected.

So far so good. You cannot go from connectedness of $f[X]$ to connectedness of $X$, simply because e.g. any map from a discrete space is continuous, so all spaces, connected or not, are continuous images of disconnected spaces. The only useful theorem in that direction that I know:

> $f:X \to Y$ is quotient (including onto) and all fibres $f^{-1}[\{y\}], y \in Y$ are connected, then if $Y$ is connected, so is $X$.

So we need extra conditions to go that way.